# What does the "U" in c defines mean (i.e. #define FOO ((uint32_t)1000U)))

Tags: c-preprocessor, unsigned

I think it could mean unsigned. But what exactly is the difference between:

```
#define FOO ((uint32_t)1000U))
```

and

```
#define FOO ((uint32_t)1000))
```

Comment: It seems you need to learn more about integer literal in C. I suggest also take a look at the difference between `0x1000u`, `1000u`, `0100u`.

Comment: To be fair, unless you knew to search for "literal" trying to derive this from web searches would be... interesting and probably not very fruitful.

Comment: @jdv Not so. Googling "u suffix in C" would have been sufficient.

Comment: Meh. Google-Fu is spread unevenly. I would never have chosen those words.

Comment: @jdv: thanks for your understanding - i really tried google search but i was not successful...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this table](http://www.rapidtables.com/prog/cref/const.htm), it indicates a constant of type `unsigned int`. The same explanation can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Comment: Why is there a cast, then?

Comment: @RadLexus Consider a case where `sizeof(unsigned) == 2`, Without the cast to `uint32_t`, FOO would have been only 2 bytes, which could cause all kinds of subtle bugs (especially in C++). Generally speaking, the `U` is redundant if you are doing the cast, but the inverse isn't true.